# Error Array to String JPG Error

Tags: php, regex, xml, url, search

I want to fetch a string to find the URLs, store them in an array and use them to build an custome output. The problem is that I get an error that I have a string to array conversion.

> NOTICE Array to string conversion on line number 21 JPEG (Array)

Can some help me, is there another way to get the URL which is stored in the array?

```
  function getURLSfromStringToImages($string) {
     $regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^" ]+/i';
     preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
      //($matches[0]);

     $tmp      = '';
        $tmpArray = $matches;

    if ( is_array( $tmpArray ) ) {

        $size  = count( $tmpArray ); //array size by using count() function
        $index = 0;

        while ( $index < $size ) {
            $tmp .= '<anhang location="REMOTE" gruppe="BILD">' . "\n"
                    . '<format>JPEG</format>' . "\n"
                    . '<daten>' . "\n"
                    . '<pfad>' .  "($tmpArray[$index])" . '</pfad>' . "\n"
                    . '</daten>' . "\n"
                    . '</anhang>' . "\n \n";
            $index ++;
        }


    } 

    echo $tmp;

}

$urls = getURLSfromStringToImages('a:3:{i:0;a:9:{s:22:"real_estate_floor_name";s:7:"Karnten";s:23:"real_estate_floor_price";s:0:"";s:31:"real_estate_floor_price_postfix";s:0:"";s:22:"real_estate_floor_size";s:0:"";s:30:"real_estate_floor_size_postfix";s:0:"";s:26:"real_estate_floor_bedrooms";s:0:"";s:27:"real_estate_floor_bathrooms";s:0:"";s:29:"real_estate_floor_description";s:0:"";s:23:"real_estate_floor_image";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:4:"4243";s:3:"url";s:70:"https://www.immo-verteiler.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/grundriss.jpg";}}i:1;a:9:{s:22:"real_estate_floor_name";s:6:"sterer";s:23:"real_estate_floor_price";s:0:"";s:31:"real_estate_floor_price_postfix";s:0:"";s:22:"real_estate_floor_size";s:0:"";s:30:"real_estate_floor_size_postfix";s:0:"";s:26:"real_estate_floor_bedrooms";s:0:"";s:27:"real_estate_floor_bathrooms";s:0:"";s:29:"real_estate_floor_description";s:0:"";s:23:"real_estate_floor_image";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:4:"4211";s:3:"url";s:76:"https://www.immo-verteiler.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Hotel-Goestling.jpg";}}i:2;a:9:{s:22:"real_estate_floor_name";s:13:"lkjölkjölkj";s:23:"real_estate_floor_price";s:0:"";s:31:"real_estate_floor_price_postfix";s:0:"";s:22:"real_estate_floor_size";s:0:"";s:30:"real_estate_floor_size_postfix";s:0:"";s:26:"real_estate_floor_bedrooms";s:0:"";s:27:"real_estate_floor_bathrooms";s:0:"";s:29:"real_estate_floor_description";s:0:"";s:23:"real_estate_floor_image";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:4:"3907";s:3:"url";s:66:"https://www.immo-verteiler.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/klein.jpg";}}}');

print_r($urls);
```

Comment: Use `$tmpArray = $matches[0];`, not `$tmpArray = $matches;`

Answer (score 0):

You need two loops

```
while ( $index < $size ) {
        foreach($tmpArray[$index] as $path)
        $tmp .= '<anhang location="REMOTE" gruppe="BILD">' . "\n"
                . '<format>JPEG</format>' . "\n"
                . '<daten>' . "\n"
                . '<pfad>' .  $path . '</pfad>' . "\n"
                . '</daten>' . "\n"
                . '</anhang>' . "\n \n";
        $index ++;
    }
```

also, I suggest you use the heredoc syntax: https://www.php-space.info/php/space/heredoc-syntax.php

Answer (score 0):

Matches are obtained into an array of arrays. You need to only grab full match values, that are stored in `$matches[0]`.

Hence, use

```
$tmpArray = $matches[0]; // not  $tmpArray = $matches;
```

Also, just use `$tmpArray[$index]` instead of `"($tmpArray[$index])"`.

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/7ZJYqb).